# Associate same looper with different threads

Tags: android, multithreading, android-handler, android-looper

In my application, I want to create multiple threads working on a single queue. To create a queue I know I need to call `Looper.prepare()`.

I want that all the other threads I create should be associated with the `looper` that I created with the first thread, How can I achieve this?

Comment: cannot do that,  what is actually your goal?

Comment: In my app i want to have a queue on which multiple worker threads will working on. As soon as a task is posted in that queue one of thread will fetch that task from the queue and start working on it.

Comment: which Thread? the Looper is associated with only one Thread so it cannot dispatch the Message to some other Thread

Comment: As per my knowledge a looper create a message queue of the thread on which it is created. I wanted other thread also to pick up messages from this queue.

Comment: see Looper private constructor in Looper. java,  it describes how a MessageQueue is created and what Thread is associated to this Looper

Answer (score 1):

Use one of Java thread safe queue class from `java.util.concurrent` package instead of Looper to achieve this goal. It's more common practice.

Share queue between threads and post task as queue entry from one thread then you can get this entry from another thread. With `BlockingQueue` you can do it easily - in one thread just call take() and it will block thread until another thread put() some entry into queue. That's all.

[Producer Consumer pattern example](http://www.journaldev.com/1034/java-blockingqueue-example-implementing-producer-consumer-problem)

[BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)  or  [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html)

[About BlockingQueue](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/blockingqueue.html)

[image]